# php: variants: which one is quicker: is_int($var) or ($var!==false) or (!($var===false))?

Tags: php

I'm writing a function where there are a lot of is_int($var) comparisons.
But $var can only be of two types: either integer or boolean false.

I was wondering which function was the fastest:

```
if (is_int($var)) {}
```

or

```
if ($var!==false) {}
```

or

```
if (!($var===false)) {}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Those are micro optimisations which you should not worry about.

Comment: 1/10000 sec vs 2/10000 sec vs 3/10000 sec

Comment: i agree with Xeon. You should not worry about such micro expression in **script language**

Comment: You guys are right, but I was just wondering. If you do this in a 100000 rows loop (= read a lot of column then check if they're booleans or not), and you do this for each client accessing your web page, this is (1/10000 * 100000 * 10) = 100 seconds. On a **10 years old server**. My question is not *that* dumb (even though it sounds like I do agree). I'm having hard times with people making assumptions ;)

Comment: Still a micro optimisation. If you've got performance problems you get much better bang for your buck looking into I/O, db access, file system reads etc. Have you thought about why you need to read 100000 rows in a loop on one page?

Comment: I was exagerating but not that much. It's a banking account: calculation on a 20 years loan: 20*12 = 240 then for each month you have a lot of information for insurance: 4 columns by guarantee and when you can have up to 10 guarantees => 10 * 40 * 240 = 9600. Then you have different "providers" for the same insurance (up to 10) => 96 000, not that far from 100 000. And I know the longest time is reading database, but once in cache, the longest time are those loop. Anyway it will cost less to upgrade the server ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

obviously answer is

```
if ($var!==false) {}
```

is faster than function, and one boolean expression is faster than two boolean expressions.

Comment: This is correct. My benchmarks suggest the difference is about 40%. Which is 0.6 seconds for a million iterations. So what you might call "negligible".

Answer (score 1):

> and one boolean expression is faster than two boolean expressions.

Never make assumptions when it comes to benchmarking. I measure:

- `if ($var!==false) {}` with an int: 1.417324
- `if ($var!==false) {}` with a boolean: 1.432197
- `if (!($var===false)) {}` with an int: 1.414805
- `if (!($var===false)) {}` with a boolean: 1.421146

Comment: Heh, ok ok, so it's micro-optimization either way. :)

Comment: Make benchmark few times. I think after `1.4` you can find random number :)))

Comment: Heh yeah, that's what I meant. There's no significant difference, as you'd first expect with twice as many operators. I suppose the optimizer is recognizing the situation and essentially turning it into the prior example.

Comment: Yes, if you want me to be honest it's ridiculous worring about boolean expressions perfomance in script language... :) But there is a question, so there is an answer :)